# How to vertically align inline-block elements with height set and test with browser tools

Tags: css

I setup this test page: http://www.cherrystoneauctions.com/test

The elements with background colors red and green are all inline-block. What I don't understand is why the green blocks are pushed down like that, since I want them all aligned at their tops. I thought the right thing to do is to set a height, which I did.

I am looking at this page with FireBug in Firefox… these types of browser tools should allow me to see quickly what is going on, I think. Perhaps I am not using the tool correctly. I would love to know what I am doing wrong as far as my CSS (to align those elements at their tops), and also how to better diagnose these kind of problems on my own, in the future. Would appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: It's because of that "Established 1967" element. And your structure is not that good anyways.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set a height on the inline-block elements. Just set `vertical-align: top;` on the green elements like so:

```
.nav0 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the links to be aligned vertically with the middle of the logo, remove the forced height on the red and green elements and set the `vertical-align` to `middle` like so:

```
#logowrap, .nav0 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Please note:**

To avoid compatibility issues with older browser that don't support `display: inline-block;` you should use the following code (taken from the Compass Framework's inline-block mixin) instead of *just* `display: inline-block;`

```
.element {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; // Set this to your preference
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```