# Align Icons at top without offsetting height

Tags: css

I am trying to align just the camera icons at the top directly below the `it's as easy as` title. However when I increase the amount of text below the title it pushes down the other components.

```
<h2>Its As Easy As ...</h2>
<div style={{margin: '10px 0', display: 'inline-block'}}> //wrapper for all 3 

    // Icon with title component
    <div style={{display: 'inline-block', margin: '20px 10px', width: '200px'}}>
      <div style={{margin: '0 0 10px'}}>
        <FontAwesome name="camera" size="4x"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 style={{margin: '10px 0'}}>{title}</h3>
        <div>{desc}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...repeat 2 more for the others
</div>
```

I am passing in some text in the `desc` attribute and when that text is long it pushes the other components down.

I tried setting a fixed height but that just increased the overall height of the components.

How would I align the icons so that the long text in the `desc` field does not affect the other components height?

[image]

Comment: You should look into using a responsive grid/columns e.g. `bootstrap`.

Comment: What does reactjs have to do with this? If you remove the reactjs stuff and leave the html and css alone, more people are likely to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align inline-block elements with height set and test with browser tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825655/how-to-vertically-align-inline-block-elements-with-height-set-and-test-with-brow)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to make your top level `div` have the following...

```
<div style={{margin: '10px 0', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'start', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
```